# When I upload Laravel website form local to live server this error that I face

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-8

When I upload Laravel website form local to live server that I face this error

`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = E70KsnO9rKtK9ATW71zmd9AfGW1ek7nAhnD2wQjS limit 1) ``

Answer (score 1):

**Please Check All of your Database connection From .env File**

```
DB_CONNECTION=MySQL
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pottered
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a list of things you have to check.

1. First, make sure the database is correctly created
2. Make sure you create a user for the database
3. Make sure this user is given all the privileges required to work on the database
4. Make sure the linkage information in file .env